# Could not connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to code a simple login in php+mysql. Everytime i hit submit button i get this error

> Could not connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

This is code that im using to connect to mysql:

```
<?php
// Create a connection to the logindb database and to MySQL.
// Set the encoding and the access details as constants:
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'johny');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'some_pass');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'biblioteczka');
// Make the connection:
$dbcon = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME)
OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );

$ID = $_POST['user'];
$PASSWORD = $_POST['pass'];   
// Set the encoding...
mysqli_set_charset($dbcon, 'utf8');    
function SignIn(){
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_POST['user'])){
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userName where user ='$_POST[user]' and pass = '$_POST[pass]'" 
                or die(mysql_error));
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass'])){
            $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'];
            echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE...";
        } else {
            echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
        }

    }
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    SignIn();
}
?>
```

I have 2 accounts root and johny, they have all priviliges and i set the passwords and i can work on database that i created.

phpmyadmin config:

[image: phpmyadmin config]

I don't know where's the problem at this points that's why im asking for help.

Sorry for my english i'm not a native speaker

Comment: Your error messages says you are trying to login as root. Your code says you are trying to log in as johny. You've copied something wrong.

Comment: Your code for the question should be **in the question**, not hosted on an external site with a link.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) that has been [removed](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) from PHP. You should select a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: **Danger**: "Not hashing at all" is [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: You are attemping to *mix* MySQLi and MySQL functions!  You connect via `mysqli_connect` then try to query via `mysql_query`.  Since you are *not* connected via the MySQL api, it tries connect on its own.

Comment: Just a note: Do not post *screenshots* of code.  If you want to include code in the question, copy and paste it in, screenshots of your editor are not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You connected to the database using the `mysqli_` library.

Then you tried to query it with the (obsolete) `mysql_` library.

The latter doesn't have a connection to the database, so it tried to open one (and failed).

Pick one library and use it consistently.

Comment: You should definitely pick `mysqli_` - mysql is obsolete and deprecated.